# how to uniformly execute benchmarks on linux

Tags: linux-kernel, benchmark

I am doing project on adapting Linux for scalable multi core architecture. I am testing Linux's performance with benchmarks. When I am running the benchmarks in the system then other programs like background processes were running in the system. I think system load due to background processes is not fixed, as a result execution time of benchmarks may vary due to system's varying load. Then how to execute benchmarks uniformly. I already searched in net and asked researchers about it but not yet able to find solution of this problem. If possible please try to help me.

Comment: One option would be to just not have the background processes running. Use a minimal system for your benchmarking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I shall try to follow your suggestion.

Comment: Well an important point to start with is exactly what are you benchmarking? That will let us know what subsystems are affected. To verify your suspicious about background processes, you can look at the SAR data after not benchmarking/load testing for a 24 hour period. On the SAR report it will show you a time series of new process entrants per second. You can use that to determine if there's a lot of processes starting up but exiting before the knock the load averages up.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [lmbench](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/) source code. Yes, I know it's pretty old. Nevertheless, the lmbench benchmarks went to a lot of effort to eliminate system load effects. Some of the benchmarks would do a computation a number of times, and do something like pick the lowest timing value.  That would get those benchmarks a maximum performance value.  Other benchmarks "warn up the cache" before doing any timing.  I'm sure you can learn a lot from lmbench.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I shall try to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you apply some common sense (eg, disable [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and don't surf the web while doing the test) and what you are timing is not totally inconsequential, the benchmarks will come out evenly -- try it.

If you run a test 50 or 100 times and notice a lot of inexplicable discrepancies, then you have a problem than needs a solution.  If not, then you don't.  A normal linux single user desktop system does not do much beyond what you tell it to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I shall try to follow your suggestion.